# How to set .input[type=text] just for one textbox

Tags: css, html

So I am working on a project and i animated a search textbox as shown here:

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  height: 30px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
```

Everything is working fine but now I have a problem, I have more textboxes on the same page and I don´t want them to be animated as this one, because the input[type=text] is changing them all. Any help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Add a `class` or `id` to it and select on that instead.

Comment: Can't you use a class? Or simply use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or [:first-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/) to select only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your css selector to be more specific instead of just `input[type=text]` to maybe `input[name=search]`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to that:

- use a class or an id in the `input`

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  height: 30px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 700px;
}

#animated {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<input id="animated" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
<hr />
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
```

- use another attribute, in this case `[name="search"]`

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  height: 30px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 700px;
}

input[name="search"] {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
<hr />
<input type="text" name="whatever" placeholder="Search..">
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to add an ID or class, then change your selector to this...

```
input[name="search"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS selector e.g. `:first-child` to choose the first input on your website.

```css
input[type=text] {
                width: 130px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border: 2px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 4px;
                font-size: 16px;
                background-color: white;
                background-image: url('searchicon.png');
                background-position: 10px 10px; 
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
                -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
                transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
                height: 30px;
            }

            input[type=text]:first-child:focus {
                width: 700px;
            }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
<hr>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
```

Another way is to set `id` to the particular input ang change css selector to `#givenID:focus`.

```css
input[type=text] {
                    width: 130px;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    border: 2px solid #ccc;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    background-color: white;
                    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
                    background-position: 10px 10px; 
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
                    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
                    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
                    height: 30px;
                }

                #inputID:focus {
                    width: 700px;
                }
```

```html
<input id="inputID" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
<hr>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your input text, such as `animated`

```
<input type="text" class="animated" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
```

Then in your CSS, modify it like this:

```
input.animated:focus {
    width: 700px;
}
```